# Bootstrap columns misaligned

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm having some issues making elements align with bootstrap. I have the code here you can have a look at:

http://cssdeck.com/labs/collab/hbcv4n9w

When the screen is small everything aligns vertically as I might expect, but as it grows it gets to the point where the last text input and it's glyph is wider that those above it, only slightly.

I was trying to debug it with a tool I found online for showing the columns, you can see a screenshot of it here:

http://tinypic.com/r/29bdgli/8

It's like it's aligning to the gutters of the columns. Any ideas?

Update:

I removed the row and placed the last element inside the form, but I am getting the same result:

```
<div class="container">

    <form class="form-horizontal">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-md-2 control-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-md-2 control-label">Password</label>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group col-md-offset-2 col-md-5">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">dfs</span>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>


</div>
```

Comment: the last group of controls is outside the `<form> </form>` element.  Also, you placed all the form controls on one `<div class="row">` and the last group on another.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 classes have -15px margin, either remove the 'row' or 'form-horizontal' Hope this is what you